# Building an array gives PHP Undefined Offset: 0

Tags: php, arrays

I can probably find a way to work around this problem I am having, but would really like to understand what language construct is causing it.

The logic is as follows, I want to build up a Session variable as the user clicks on a route on Google Maps that is an array of waypoints.  The POST packet is a JSON object:

```
?waypoint={"waypoint":[{"lat":"23.3","long":"145"}]}
```

The code that accepts the POST and interprets is:

```
    <?php
     session_start ();
    //session_destroy();
    //die;
    //$waypoints[] = array();  <<== uncomment this and the behaviour changes
    if (isset ( $_GET ['waypoint'] )) {
        $waypoint =  $_GET ['waypoint'];
        $waypoint = json_decode($waypoint,true);
        print_r($waypoint['waypoint']); <<<========output 1
        if (isset ( $_SESSION ['waypoints'] )) {
            $waypoints = $_SESSION ['waypoints'];
            $waypoints [] = $waypoint['waypoint'];
            $_SESSION ['waypoints']=$waypoints;
        } else {
            $_SESSION ['waypoints'] = $waypoint['waypoint']; 
            $waypoints[] = $waypoint['waypoint'];
        }
    }

    foreach( $_SESSION ['waypoints'] as $var) {
        var_dump($var);    <<<<====== Output 2
        echo($var[0]['lat']); <<<<==== Here is the problem.

    };
    ?>
```

Here is the problem.  The first time through, **Output 1 and 2** give the outputs below and the **correct value for lat is output = 23.3**

```
  **Output 1:** Array ( [0] => Array ( [lat] => 23.3 [long] => 145 ) )
  -------------------------------------------------------
  **Output 2:**
  array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'lat' => string '23.3' (length=4)
      'long' => string '145' (length=3)
```

The second call, produces an error `Notice: Undefined offset: 0`  and subsequent calls are fine, that is the array builds up as expected.  Now if I uncomment the statement `waypoints[] = array();`  It bombs on the first pass, yet all subsequent runs are okay.

Is anyone able to interpret this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Can we assume you do actually have a `session_start()` in this code that you have not shown us?

Comment: Yes, sorry I left it out.  I will add now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Issue**

your issue is in the first line of the `else` condition that reads `$_SESSION ['waypoints'] = $waypoint['waypoint'];`.

**The Fix**

If you change it to `$_SESSION ['waypoints'][] = $waypoint['waypoint'];` then you should resolve the errors you are getting.

**The Explanation**

What you are looking for in `echo($var[0]['lat']);` is for the *values* of each waypoint to contain an array which they do when they are set in your `if` (`$waypoints [] = $waypoint['waypoint'];`) condition but not in your `else` condition (`$_SESSION ['waypoints'] = $waypoint['waypoint'];`)

Comment: Thankyou.  Yes that fixed it.  I agree with RiggsFolly that it is more complex than it needs to be, but it grew as I tried to get to the bottom of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be making life a little more complex than it need to be.

```
session_start();

if (isset ( $_GET ['waypoint'] )) {

    $waypoint = json_decode($_GET ['waypoint'],true);
    print_r($waypoint['waypoint']); <<<========output 1

    // as whatever happens we are just adding a waypoint
    // to an array of waypoints in the SESSION variable
    // this one line will create the $_SESSION['waypoints'][]
    // or add a new [] to it.

    $_SESSION['waypoints'][] = $waypoint;
}

// Just as belt and brace check, 
// assuming someone could try to pass this code some rubbish
// like xxx.php&hacker=yes we ought to check before attempting to
// use the $_SESSION['waypoints'] that one exists

if ( isset($_SESSION['waypoints'] ) {
    foreach( $_SESSION['waypoints'] as $var) {
        // $var is now a waypoint array so it is not $var[0]['lat']
        echo sprintf( 'Latitude = %s - Longitude = %s', 
                            $var['lat'], 
                            $var['long']
                    );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - especially the comment regarding "belt and brace check"  I will recast my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
else {
    $_SESSION ['waypoints'][] = $waypoint['waypoint']; 
}
```